# Automate a react native Android application using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

I'm trying to inspect element on react native app
but unfortunately I could not find any element on it, I have use ui automator viewer and appium inspector.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no problem to inspect react native application with [appium desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases), you can check [article](https://saucelabs.com/blog/testing-a-hybrid-mobile-app-using-appium) on Sauce Labs blog with pretty good details and iOS RN app/python example.

It's a bit tricky to uniquely identify UI elements, but still possible with setting unique `accessibilityLabel` for the View on RN side and search for it with `AccessibilityId` locator strategy in Appium.

Provide more details in case you need additional help.

Unfortunately, without having accessibilityLabel in Views of RN app, you are limited to use xpath locator and search by element text, like `"//android.widget.TextView[contains(text(), 'Skip')]"`.

Avoid using strict `@text=` as it might not work for every element ,e.g. if text split in 2 lines on some device.

Comment: Actually, none of the above worked. because in our app we don't have any accessibilitId or accessibilityLabel. The only thing that can be use is xpath, I have tried to use  xpath with text. ex "//android.widget.TextView[@text='Skip']" but non of them have worked the selenium didn't click on the item.

Comment: @AzizaHassan it should be possible to set like <View accessibilityLabel=MyUniqueId"> in your ReactNative app and then with Appium parse it with driver.find_elements_by_accessibility_id('MyUniqueId'). Its proven solution not only on my project, but by the React Native developers as well.

Comment: https://github.com/garthenweb/react-native-e2etest another example: The accessibilityLabel is the best property to exposes queryable information in Android and iOS. The downside is, it's visible to the user (at least if he/she is using accessibility tools to query this information). That said, you should define proper labels so users with accessibility tools aren't confused by your selectors. Talk to your developers

Comment: Totally agree, but the app is already on production.Is there anything I can use rather that the accessibilityid

Comment: Unfortunately, without having accessibilityLabel  in Views of RN app, you are limited to use xpath locator and search by element text, like `"//android.widget.TextView[contains(text(), 'Skip')]"`. Avoid using strict `text()= ` as it might not work everywhere